# How to convert lots of MIBs?

Tags: snmp, mib

Regarding my latest question on this site; I'm still struggling with adding MIB files to my snmptt server. I have this huge pile of MIBs from both Cisco and Juniper, and snmptt needs handlers for them. They provide a tool called snmpttconvertmib, and I can write shell scrip that executes it for each MIB, but here is the problem: They depend on each other...

So converting a whole directory of MIBs will fail, because the order in which the files are translated is wrong. Is there any known tool/way that takes care of this and lets me do what I need?

Using Debian btw.

Answer (score 1):

The `snmpttconvertmib` script relies on the [the Net-SNMP `snmptranslate` utility](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmptranslate.html) to process the MIB files behind-the-scenes. The `snmptranslate` tool looks for dependent MIB files in the directories specified in the `MIBDIRS` environment variable. Are you certain that `snmptranslate` is looking in the right place in your scenario?

Comment: My MIBDIRS environment variable is set to the folder where my mibs are, so I guess that it is correct?

Comment: @HaroldHolsappel - Sounds like it. (It was worth a shot, at least... >smile<)

Comment: Would it work to `cat` all MIBs into one file and then run `snmpttconvertmib` on it?

Comment: Hmm nope. Doesnt work, because now all the import statements are failing.